# Split string which contains item and value into Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, string, dictionary, split

What is the best way to split the name/description of the value into a `dictionary <string, string>`?

```
string test = postedByUser='Jason, Bourne' postedById='48775' Text='Some text in here' postedDate='2020-04-21'
```

so ideally i want

```
dictionary key = postedByUser, value = Jason, Bourne
dictionary key = postedById, value = 48775
```

etc

code added so far

```
string test = @"postedByUser=Jason, Bourne' postedById='48775' Text='Some text in here' postedDate='2020-04-21'";

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>(); 

List<string> lst = test.Split('=').ToList(); 

foreach(string item in lst) 
{     
    // cant figure out how edit the orginal string to remove the item that has 
    //been split by the '=' 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. i need to be able to send an email based off that split information in a windows application. i have tried to split the orginal string value on the '=' sign but that then means i need to further edit the string to then try and grab the second value. i cant figure out that bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can the following code will solve your problem but I suggest you to add more exception handling to make the code robust.

```
string test = @"postedByUser='Jason, Bourne' postedById='48775' Text='Some text in here' postedDate='2020-04-21'";

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

List<string> keyvalues = test.Split("' ").ToList();
foreach(var keyvalue in keyvalues)
{
    var splitKeyValue = keyvalue.Split('=');
    dict.Add(splitKeyValue[0], splitKeyValue[1]);
}
```

EDIT:

For .NET Framework 4.6,

```
List<string> keyvalues = test.Split(new string[] { "' " }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
```

Comment: Compilation error (line 12, col 28): The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
Compilation error (line 12, col 39): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Answer (score 1):

Try this one (quite ugly but should work):

```
var dict = test.Split("' ").Select(t=>string.Concat(t,"'").Split("=")).ToDictionary(t=>t[0],t=>t[1]);
```

Comment: this produces an error An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe

Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: try using .NET 4.7.2

Comment: in net 4.72 you have to replace Split("'' ") with Split(new string[] { "' "}, StringSplitOptions.None) and it still  works as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.Split(..)` to separate out your string for processing.

[String.Split documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8)

First split the string based on a `' '` space character as a separator e.g.

```
var splitStrings = test.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.None);
```

then run through each string in strings and separate using `'='`. This will give you a list of 2 strings where the first is your key and the second is your value.

Comment: I wonb be able to use the ' ' for the first seperator as the "Text" key contains spaces too...

Answer (score 0):

[Regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions) can be used to solve this problem:

```
string text = @"postedByUser='Jason, Bourne' postedById='48775' Text='Some text in here' postedDate='2020-04-21'";
Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, @"(\w+)=\'(.+?)\'"))
{
    result.Add(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Here is [complete sample](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qowZSI).